# Weird cartoon with screaming, spinning-face villain... that I’ve been trying to figure out for 20 years!

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

Cartoon with a scene of a hero and villain, which I remember as a screaming, spinning-faces statue thing... I think it was white colored?  And a boy, running through a crumbling castle.  Would have been early '90s or earlier... not sure about length, but it played on US TV.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you can recall any further details, please edit them into your question. The more info you provide, the better your chance of getting a correct answer.

Comment: In addition to what @LogicDictates wrote, [here's a checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/19561) that might help you remember more details which you can [edit] in.

Comment: Note to @LogicDictates: using `[edit]` in your comment creates an automagic link for editing.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Once you've managed to [edit] more details in please take a look at the [tour] to see more about the website, and how we work

Comment: “early '90s or earlier”  — sounds like you've been trying to figure it out for closer to 30 years at this point.